# Why is Feb 29 reported as invalid date?

Tags: python, datetime

```
import datetime

tstr = "02-29 13:34:57.041"
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(tstr, '%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

My script reports such an error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/_strptime.py", line 579, in _strptime_datetime
    return cls(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: day is out of range for month
```

Why? Today is Feb 29, 2024.

Comment: Can't wait until the year 4000... (I think that's the next, less publicized, exception in the ever-finer-grained attempts to keep the calendar in sync with observation.)

Comment: @Matthias actually I assumed you already knew, but since you didn't explain I added that for the passersby.

Comment: @chepner will there be a [year-4000-edition of Lotus 123](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/office/troubleshoot/excel/wrongly-assumes-1900-is-leap-year)? I'll buy it!

Answer (score 3):

If you dont specify a year, it will parse it as 1900 and then there is no 29 feb.

Add 2024 and `%Y` and it works fine

```
import datetime

tstr = "02-29-2024 13:34:57.041"
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(tstr, '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')

print(dt)
#2024-02-29 13:34:57.041000
```

Comment: It's worth noting that 1900 was *not* a leap year, even though it's divisible by 4.  There are additional rules for years divisible by 100 or 400.